# Battery increase current after being fully charged

Tags: batteries, current, charging

I have 8 used UPS batteries. All fully charged at 13.3V standby voltage. I wanted to test them with my battery tester. The batteries have 5Ah at 12V. Since they are Lead Acid i can expect to get around the half capacity when i discharge. Most of them giving me 2 to 2.5Ah.

The test first charges the batteries to 14.7V with current limit of 1A. Wait 5 min, discharge with 1.5A to 10.5V, wait 5 min, charging back up to 14.7 with 1A limit.

After they get charged the charger waits until the battery drops under 200mA charge current to end the test. The battery never reaches this current.

There is the strange part:
The battery current starts to rise again until it hits 1A and the voltage then dropping significantly. At this point the battery starts to get warm.

What happens in the battery that it shows this behavior?

Right now, i have a battery connected to the exact same charger at a current limit of 300mA. The battery charges since around 20h and put in over 7Ah.

Would really like to understand this.

Comment: Shouldn't I see the Voltage drop to around 11V if I let the battery sit for a while? Wondering why it's at 13V to 13.2V after some days.

Comment: You are absolutely correct -- if there were a shorted cell, the voltage would drop quickly after charger was removed. The other possibility is high internal cell resistance, as occurs when the electrolyte is slowly decomposed through repeated charging.